# Php in_array() not working as expected

Tags: php, html, foreach, multiple-select

I am currently working on a multiple select drop-down list. I need to display the selected values on an edit form.

`in_array()` is not working as I expect, do I have an error in my logic?

The code to display the selected values from the database is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="selectbasic">Update Artist Selection</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <select id="artists1" multiple="multiple" name="id_artist_fk[]" class="form-control ">
            <?php
            foreach ($artist_list as $key => $value) {
                if (in_array($value['id_artist'], $current_artist_list, true)) {
                    $selected = "selected='selected'";
                }
                // print_r($value['id_artist']. "==". $current_artist_list);
                echo "<option value=\"{$value['id_artist']}\" {$selected}>{$value['name']} {$value['surname']}</option>";
            }
            ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `$artist_list` is gotten via:

```
public function get_artist_list() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_v_artist WHERE status != 0;";
    $result = $this->database->doSelectQuery($sql);
    $artists = array();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
            $artist = array(
                'id_artist' => $row['id_artist'],
                'name' => $row['name'],
                'surname' => $row['surname'],
                'status' => $row['status']
            );
            array_push($artists, $artist);
        }
    }
    return $artists;
}
```

The `$current_artist_list` is gotten via:

```
$current_artist_list = $vid->get_artistsID_for_video($_POST['id_video']);
```

`get_artistsID_for_video` is:

```
public function get_artistsID_for_video($video_id) {
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT
                tbl_video_artist.id_artist_fk
                FROM tbl_video_artist
                left join tbl_v_artist
                ON tbl_v_artist.id_artist = tbl_video_artist.id_artists
                WHERE tbl_video_artist.id_video_fk = {$video_id};";
        //echo $sql;
        $result = $this->database->doSelectQuery($sql);
        $artists = array();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                $artist = array(
                    'id_artist_fk' => $row['id_artist_fk']
                );
                array_push($artists, $artist);
            }
        }
        return $artists;
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $ex->getMessage();
        $ex->getFile();
    }
}
```

Please help point me in the right direction.

---

I have edited the get_artistsID_for_video as follows:

```
public function get_artistsID_for_video($video_id) {
    try {
        $sql = "SELECT
                tbl_video_artist.id_artist_fk
                FROM tbl_video_artist
                left join tbl_v_artist
                ON tbl_v_artist.id_artist = tbl_video_artist.id_artists
                WHERE tbl_video_artist.id_video_fk = {$video_id};";
        //echo $sql;
        $result = $this->database->doSelectQuery($sql);
       // $artists = array();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                $artist [] = $row['id_artist_fk'];
               // array_push($artists, $artist);
            }
             return $artist;
        }

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        $ex->getMessage();
        $ex->getFile();
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of `$artist = array(
                        'id_artist_fk' => $row['id_artist_fk']
                    );
                    array_push($artists, $artist);`  use `$artist[] = $row['id_artist_fk'];`  in your last function  (shown in question)

Comment: i did that @Anantif ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                    $artist [] = $row['id_artist_fk'];
                   // array_push($artists, $artist);
                }
            }

Comment: @Anant, please check my edited question

Comment: no @Anant it isnt

Comment: Maybe it will help if you did a `var_dump` of `$artist_list` and `$current_artist_list` to check what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `in_array` manual:

> in_array — Checks if a value exists in an array

So, what checks your `in_array($value['id_artist'], $current_artist_list, true)`?

It checks that in `$current_artist_list` exists value of `$value['id_artist']`. For example, if `$value['id_artist']` is **20**, `in_array` checks if value **20** is in your array.

But value **20** is **NOT** in your `$current_artist_list` array.

Because format of each element in your `$current_artist_list` is `array('id_artist_fk' => $row['id_artist_fk'])`.

So, you're searching for **20**, but value which you store is `('id_artist_fk' => 20)`.

`20` **NOT EQUALS** `array`.

The fix is in `get_artistsID_for_video()`:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $artists[] = $row['id_artist_fk'];
}
```

Now you search for `20` in array where every element is a number **too**.

Making your search even **faster** (still in `get_artistsID_for_video`):

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    // create array key with value of artist id
    $artists[$row['id_artist_fk']] = 1;
}
```

And replace `in_array` with:

```
// check for existence of a key, not value.
if (!empty($current_artist_list[$value['id_artist']])) {
    $selected = "selected='selected'";
}
```

Comment: Thanks u_mulder: But it still does not display any: please check my question: it is updated

Comment: Output `$value`, `$current_artist_list` and see what is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Please check that $current_artist_list must be single array. i.e $current_artist_list[0] = 1;
$current_artist_list[1] = 2;

Which will match your id with condition. Right now it's looks like your $current_artist_list is associative array value having with key. Try to push only value as i mentioned above OR change the code as below.

```
$artists = array();
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
                $artist = array(
                    'id_artist_fk' => $row['id_artist_fk']
                );
                array_push($artists, $row['id_artist_fk']);
            }
        }
```